# Django forms concurrency/validation problem

Tags: django, forms, concurrency

I have a question regarding django form validation and concurrency. Say I have a invoice form where the form clean checks if on of the invoice positions about to be created already exists in an other invoice (check is executed via querying the database!). If so it raises an validation error.

Now I have the case that 2 users create a new invoice with the identical position and click on save at the same moment. The form validation passes in both cases because the first invoice was not saved to database while the second one passes the form validation.

Now I have 2 invoices with the same position which should not be possible.

Is there a decent way to solve this problem?

Thanks for your help!
Jonas

Comment: Why don't you check at model.save(). Have you also tried validating at database level?, for example using unique together in your model?. It would be helpful if you add your models to your questikn.

Comment: Unfortunately its not unique, because its allowed to be in an other invoice if that invoice has status cancelled. Its only not allowed in other invoices with status draft and completed. Then I would like to render a form error to the user, so is forms clean not the place for that?

Comment: Is it possible to set a session token in your view which disables other users in the same position you're actually trying to use?...